# Vue component doesn't reload with getter data (not reactive)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have this ecommerce mock app in Vue and Vuex. This page shows a list of phones and there is a filter which filters phones based on the phone brands through checkboxes.

The problem is the page doesn't refresh straight away after I click the checkbox to filter. If I click another page and click back to the original page, then the page gets filtered.

[image]

The is my source code. Some code is removed for brevity.

Product.vue

```js
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
import BrandFilter from "../components/BrandFilter";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      products: this.$store.getters.filterProducts
    };
  },
  components: { BrandFilter }
};
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3"><BrandFilter></BrandFilter></div>
      <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div class="row">
          <div v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">            
                <h4 class="card-title product__title">
                  {{ product.title }}
                </h4>                            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

BrandFilter.vue

```js
export default {
  name: "BrandFilter",
  data() {
    return {
      brands: this.$store.state.brands
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onChangeSelectBox(e) {
      debugger;
      const name = e.target.name;
      const value = e.target.checked;
      if (value) {
        this.$store.commit("addBrandToFilter", name);
      } else {
        this.$store.commit("removeBrandFromFilter", name);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="card mb-3">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h3>Brands</h3>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group flex-row flex-wrap">
      <li class="list-group-item flex-50" v-for="brand in brands" :key="brand">
        <label class="custom-checkbox text-capitalize">
          {{ brand }}
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            :name="brand"
            class="custom-checkbox__input"
            @input="onChangeSelectBox($event)"
          />
          <span class="custom-checkbox__span"></span>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

store/index.js

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import { phones } from "../data/phones";
import { brands } from "../data/brands";
import { brandFilter } from "../filters/brandFilter";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state: {
    products: phones,
    brands: brands,
    cart: [],
    brandFilter: ""
  },
  getters: {
    filterProducts(state) {
      debugger;
      const brands = state.brandFilter;
      const filterByBrandArr = brandFilter(state.products, brands);
      return filterByBrandArr;
    }
  },
  mutations: {    
    addBrandToFilter: (state, brand) => {
      debugger;
      if (state.brandFilter.includes(brand)) return void 0;

      state.brandFilter += brand;
    },
    removeBrandFromFilter: (state, brand) => {
      debugger;
      const reg = new RegExp(brand, "gi");
      state.brandFilter = state.brandFilter.replace(reg, "");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Not sure what `brandFilter` actually does in your Vuex getter, seems a bit over complicated. In the `onChangeSelectBox(e)` method, try to not call any mutations but rather dispatch some actions (mapActions could be helpful). Also, I'm seeing that you're using vanilla debug tools, try out the Vue devtools, it will help you have more insight on the current state, on the mutations and the events in an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set a data item to a getter in *Product.vue*, it gets assigned only once.  If the getter changes, the data doesn't change with it:

```js
data() {
  return {
    products: this.$store.getters.filterProducts  // ❌ Incorrect
  }
}
```

Use a computed instead with `mapGetters` to keep the component data synced with the Vuex data:

```js
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
```

```js
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['filterProducts'])  // ✅ Correct
}
```

Change your template to use that computed:

```html
<div v-for="product in filterProducts" :key="product.id">            
   <h4 class="card-title product__title">
      {{ product.title }}
   </h4>                            
</div>
```